# Use JQuery/Javascript to show a live preview of checkbox formatting options

Tags: javascript, jquery

The purpose of this script is to show a "live preview" of how text will be formatted once the user selects a checkbox. It is being used in a Wordpress plugin.

If user selects the "bold" checkbox, the Lorem Ipsum "div" text should appear with opening and closing "strong" tags.

This has worked sporadically, such as when I write the script only to address one or the other, i.e., "strong" **or** "em", but I want to be able to have the paragraph (the parText object) always reflect **all** the choices.

I imagine something is wrong with my function definition and callback. JQuery is less familiar to me than PHP. Here is the code I am working with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    parText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ornare tempus magna, eu tempor nisi posuere at. In sagittis nulla quis metus convallis ornare sit amet id ligula. Duis posuere scelerisque justo, in consequat nulla euismod et. Donec consequat nec magna vel aliquet. Suspendisse felis leo, aliquet at egestas non, placerat non erat. Pellentesque placerat quam nec erat fringilla, ut accumsan lorem pharetra. In volutpat nunc at ligula elementum lacinia. Donec sit amet lectus lobortis enim tempus semper at ut lacus.';
    //SET THE VALUE OF THE HTML TAGS
        boldOpen = '<strong>';
        boldClosed = '</strong>';
        italicsOpen = '<em>';
        italicsClosed = '</em>';

    //FUNCTION TO RETURN HTML VALUE
        function htmlOpenCloseTags() {
        //bold and italics
        if ( $('#select_bold').prop('checked') == true && $('#select_italics').prop('checked') == true ) {
            htmlOpen = boldOpen + italicsOpen;
            htmlClose = boldClosed + italicsClosed;
        } 
        //bold only
        else if ( $('#select_bold').prop('checked') == true && $('#select_italics').prop('checked') == false ) {
            htmlOpen = boldOpen;
            htmlClose = boldClosed;
        }
        //italics only
        else if ( $('#select_bold').prop('checked') == false && $('#select_italics').prop('checked') == true ) {
            htmlOpen = italicsOpen;
            htmlClose = italicsClosed;
        }
        //neither
        else {
            htmlOpen = '';
            htmlClose = '';
        }
        var output = htmlOpen + parText + htmlClose;
        return output;
        }

    //BOLD LIVE PREVIEW
        $('#select_bold').change(function(){
            $('#live_preview').hide();
            htmloutput = htmlOpenCloseTags();
            $('#live_preview').html(htmloutput);
            $('#live_preview').fadeIn('fast');
        });

    //ITALICS LIVE PREVIEW
        $('#select_italics').change(function(){
            $('#live_preview').hide();
            $('#live_preview').html(htmlOpen + parText + htmlClose);
            $('#live_preview').fadeIn('fast');
        });
```

//end jquery
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/W8774/1/.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ornare tempus magna, eu tempor nisi posuere at. In sagittis nulla quis metus convallis ornare sit amet id ligula. Duis posuere scelerisque justo, in consequat nulla euismod et. Donec consequat nec magna vel aliquet. Suspendisse felis leo, aliquet at egestas non, placerat non erat. Pellentesque placerat quam nec erat fringilla, ut accumsan lorem pharetra. In volutpat nunc at ligula elementum lacinia. Donec sit amet lectus lobortis enim tempus semper at ut lacus.';

    //FUNCTION TO RETURN HTML VALUE
    function htmlOpenCloseTags() {
        var htmlOpen = '';
        var htmlClose = '';

        if ($('#select_bold').prop('checked')) {
            htmlOpen = '<strong>' + htmlOpen;
            htmlClose += '</strong>';
        } 

        if ($('#select_italics').prop('checked')) {
            htmlOpen = '<em>' + htmlOpen;
            htmlClose += '</em>';
        }
        return htmlOpen + parText + htmlClose;
    }

    //BOLD LIVE PREVIEW
    $('#select_bold').change(function(){
        $('#live_preview').hide();
        var htmloutput = htmlOpenCloseTags();
        $('#live_preview').html(htmloutput);
        $('#live_preview').fadeIn('fast');
    });

    //ITALICS LIVE PREVIEW
    $('#select_italics').change(function(){
        $('#live_preview').hide();
        var htmloutput = htmlOpenCloseTags();
        $('#live_preview').html(htmloutput);
        $('#live_preview').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Right now it's just hiding the paragraph text, regardless of which checkbox is checked. I like the use of the "+=". This is essentially the javascript equivalent of ".=" in PHP? One question, why use "+=" for the htmlClose variable and not for the htmlOpen variable? Why the difference?

Comment: Yes `+=` in Javascript is the same as `.=` in PHP, for appending text. The difference is because of what happens when you have multiple options selected. For each style the opening tag will be prepended and the closing tag will be appended. For example if you have bold selected the `htmlOpen` variable will be `<strong>` and the `htmlClose` variable will be `</strong>`. If italics is also selected then the `htmlOpen` variable will be `<em><strong>` and the `htmlClose` variable will be `</strong></em>`.

Comment: @ChrisBuck you said "Right now it's just hiding the paragraph text, regardless of which checkbox is checked.", do you still have any problem that needs to be solved? In the jsfiddle I posted it seems to be working fine.

Comment: It's interesting. This is working on the jsfiddle site, I see that, but it's not working on my Wordpress plugin admin page. It's gotta be something with the way my PHP is creating echoing the HTML, right?

Comment: Anyway, with the jsfiddle, I should be able to figure out where the error is. I'll post an update if I can. Your code is definitely correct, though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I had an outdated version of JQuery library from Google. That was the difference. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok great. If possible, update your jQuery version, otherwise let me know what version you're using.